# Are these row operations correct?

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

This is from a video in an online course. The lesson is on finding the inverse of a matrix using reduced row echelon form. The row operations the instructor uses here are not making sense to me.

R1: [1 2 3]
R2: [0 1 3]

Shouldn't R1 - 2(R2) for column 3 be 3 - 2(3) = 3 - 6 = -3, not -4?

[screenshot of video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCDr0.png)
[image]

Comment: You are correct.  Sometimes people in videos make mistakes, just like people not in videos.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are indeed correct; the screenshot from the video has the mistake you identify, and hence, is incorrect.  (The same problem on occasion happens in textbooks, and sometimes professors make silly mistakes, or typos, too).

Just one additional comment, some prefer the notation that indicates row operations **and** the target row.  E.g., in this case, some (and I) would right $[R_1-2R_2] \to R_1$, to make explicit that we are reassigning new values to $R_1$,  by using the original values of $R_1$  and subtracting  $2R_2$ from those values.

Comment: Now I feel weird about never having used any particular notation for row/column operations.

Comment: I'm just suggesting an adjustment to the video's material.  Using it helps document what you're doing, and helps you to be able to revisit your work and know how you transitioned from one matrix to another.

Comment: Sure. I'm not  saying it's *wrong* to have a consistent notation for those things. It's just that I don't think I was taught anything like that , nor did I come up with it myself (at least not consistently enough to remember, there was probably some ad hoc stuff). Which is kind of weird in hindisght, since it makes perfect sense to have *some* fixed way of expressing these things.